# Problemas con move_uploaded_file

Tags: php

muy buenas tardes ! 
sucede que estoy moviendo un archivo cargado, pero al momento de ver en el servidor el archivo no se mueve ! el problema es que ayer si funcionaba , pero por problemas toco cambiar de servidor, sin embargo el nuevo servidor cuenta con las mismas características en el cual tiene PHP 5.6.

el código que estoy usando es (fragmento del código):

```
$fecha = Date('Y-m-d-H-i-s');
$ruta = "../view/tmp_files/";
// renombra el archivo con la información anterior
$archivo = $fecha."-".$_FILES['excel']['name'];
// mueve el archivo a la ruta ingresada
//echo "$ruta$archivo";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['excel']['tmp_name'], "$ruta$archivo")) {
    echo "ok";
}else {
    echo "fail";
}
```

sin embargo la carpeta tmp_files tiene los permisos adecuados 777
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero alguien sepa que es lo que pasa y pueda ayudarme.

saludos.

PDT: el servidor es un CentOS 7

Answer (score 0):

Toma en cuenta que el path que utilizas es relativo a la carpeta del script.  Verifica que las carpetas "../view/tmp_files" sean accesibles partiendo de la ubicacion del script en el que está el código.  No está de más que verifiques si el archivo logra cargar, puede ser que ya no tengas espacio en disco o que la extensión no sea permitida por alguna política.

También, considera utilizar otro esquema de permisos en vez de 777 puesto que cualquier usuario podría escribirla.

Comment: pues men ! la verdad no se que mas hacer ! como dije, en el server anterior si movia y lo mismo en el local , asi que la ruta considero que esta bien . pero por motivos de fuerza mayor se migro el aplicativo a otro servidor pero con las mismas caracteristicas :/ y que mas podria usar en vez de 777 ?